# Replace variable value of view angular 7

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I'm using the editor ckeditor 5 for generate document, with some text like : `Hello {{nameUser}}`

this data is stocked in datastore.

when i get the data of the etidor for generate document i wish replace the variable `{{nameUser}}` with value of local variable `nameUser = value;`.

I found the solution with the function `replace` or `split().join()` but i have more variables and the traitement is more long with this.

how i can replace directly the variable entroured by  `{{ }}`.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it directly with {{ }} but you could replace those with <%= %>

And then use: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but she don't work :/ !!